# Bayesian analysis...applied to the real world

Tags: bayesian, bayes-theorem

33% of patients with *subarachnoid haemorrhage (bleeding from a burst brain aneurysm)* die before they reach hospital. Of those who survive, 15% have another brain-bleed within 2 weeks. 45% of those who have a second brain-bleed die. Using Bayesian analysis,  what is the proportion of people who die from subarachnoid haemorrhage?

MY SOLUTION

- I had to draw out the probability tree and calculated the overall percentage of death after subarachnoid haemorrhage being 0.37.
- I can't for the life of me work out what the prior and likelihood are in this question.

Comment: I don't see anything about probability here.  If you start with a sample  $S$, $.33S$ die fast, $.45\times.15\times (1-.33) S$ die a bit later (in what sounds disturbingly like a spider related illness).  Add these up and you get a hair over your $.37$.  No probability in sight.

Comment: I thought the same - wanted to confirm. A certain 'professor' who posed that question clearly does bot know what she was talking about ;) Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Here you apply   the Law of Total Probability. First though one must  define the events clearly.